# Can't connect to Postgres via SSH in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, ssh, psycopg2, ssh-tunnel

I need to connect to Postgres DB via SSH tunnel. I use following code:

```
try:

    with SSHTunnelForwarder(
         (ssh_host, ssh_port),
         ssh_username=ssh_user,
         ssh_password=ssh_password, 
         remote_bind_address=(sql_hostname, 5432)) as server:
         
         server.start()
         print("server connected")

         params = {
             'database': sql_database,
             'user': sql_username,
             'password': sql_password,
             'host': sql_hostname,
             'port': server.local_bind_port
             }

         conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
         curs = conn.cursor()
         print("database connected")

except:
    print("Connection Failed")
```

As the result I get this warnings in the command line:

```
2023-02-09 23:09:16,285| ERROR   | Password is required for key /Users/aleksandrlozko/.ssh/id_rsa
2023-02-09 23:09:16,286| ERROR   | Password is required for key /Users/aleksandrlozko/.ssh/id_ed25519
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aleksandrlozko/stages-customer-service-dashboard-atollhoding/modules/db/connect.py", line 73, in <module>
    db = psql.PostgreSQLDB(
  File "/Users/aleksandrlozko/stages-customer-service-dashboard-atollhoding/modules/db/psql.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.pool = psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/activity-dashboard-atollholding/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/pool.py", line 59, in __init__
    self._connect()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/activity-dashboard-atollholding/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/pool.py", line 63, in _connect
    conn = psycopg2.connect(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/activity-dashboard-atollholding/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "172.26.201.14", port 5432 failed: Operation timed out
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Through the pdAdmin it is possible to connect, but not using Python. What could be the problem? And at what stage am I making a mistake?

Comment: Don't post text as images.

Comment: The 'host' param should probably be set to 'localhost', as that where you find your end of the tunnel.  You are trying to connect to the wrong end of the tunnel.

Comment: @jjanes I set 'localhost' and tried to print curs with sql query "SELECT VERSION()". My result is None. I connected to db right or not?

Comment: If you didn't get an error, then you should be connected.  This sounds like a new issue, and there isn't enough info to know what is going on.  Maybe start a new question showing the new code.